# How to add a delay when using forward-geocoding to get Latitude and Longitude for many addresses in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding, delay

I have some addresses inside my Core Data and I need to get their Latitude and Longitude. The number of addresses is around 150 to 200. I've read that iOS limits you to 50 geocodes per minute in the thread [iPhone iOS5 CLGeocoder how to geocode a large (200) set of addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619879/iphone-ios5-clgeocoder-how-to-geocode-a-large-200-set-of-addresses). I need to know how can I fire 50 geocodes in that minute and after that fire another 50 and so on. Executing the code I get the following error:

> Geocode failed with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)"

The user nob1984 suggested a possible solution in the thread I mentioned:

> If you need to have everything geocoded at once, you'll need to chain your geocodings together with delays between each chunk and show some sort of busy indicator until you are done. Which could be some time with large sets of geocodings.

But I have no idea how to do these delays to work properly. Any help and suggestions are welcomed! Thanks

Here is the code:

```
...
NSArray *arrayOfRoutePoints = fetchedObjects;
[self geolocateGroup:arrayOfRoutePoints];
...

- (void)geolocateGroup:(NSArray *)array {
for (RoutePoint *rp in array) {
    if ([rp.addressLatitude intValue] == 0) {
        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        [self geolocateRoutePoint:rp];

        dispatch_group_leave(group);

        while(dispatch_group_wait(group,DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)){
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                     beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3.0f]];
        }
    }
}    
}     

- (void)geolocateRoutePoint:(RoutePoint *)c {
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@ %@ %@ %@",
                           c.addressName,
                           c.addressNumber,
                           @"SOME CITY",
                           @"SOME STATE",
                           @"SOME COUNTRY"];

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString
             completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                 if (error) {
                     NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                     return;
                 }

                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
                 {
                     CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                     CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
                     c.addressLatitude =  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
                     c.addressLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];
                 }
             }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm maybe just use "afterDelay" in your GCD, instead of a NSDate.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(geolocateGroup) 
withObject:@"Grand Central Dispatch" afterDelay:3.0];
```

Comment: Hi @Droidnoid. Thank you for the suggestion. Using performSelector with afterDelay the result was the same: only 50 adresses got the Latitude and Longitude information. The other addresses got the error: kCLErrorDomain error 2. I think my code is firing the geolocateRoutePoint method 150 times in "one shot" instead of firing one by one in an interval of 3 seconds. The usage of this performSelector gives me an idea! Now it's going to work. Thank you! I'll post the answer in a moment.

Comment: @Droidnoid: Why are you passing in a string (`@Grand Central Dispatch`) to that selector when it takes an array?

Comment: great tip, but 1.5 seconds are enough

Answer (score 1):

I got an idea while replying Droidnoid and it works.

Here's the deal: recursion. After the geocode complete, it starts a new one geocode request in time interval of 3 seconds. I changed to be only one method now.

```
...
NSMutableArray *arrayOfRoutePoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchedObjects];
[self geolocateRoutePoint:arrayOfRoutePoints];
...

- (void)geolocateRoutePoint:(NSMutableArray *)mutableArrayWithRoutePoints {

if ([mutableArrayWithRoutePoints count] > 0) {
    RoutePoint *c = [mutableArrayWithRoutePoints objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([c.addressLatitude intValue] == 0) {
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@ %@ %@ %@",
                                   c.addressName,
                                   c.addressNumber,
                                   @"SOME CITY",
                                   @"SOME STATE",
                                   @"SOME COUNTRY"];

        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString
                     completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                         [mutableArrayWithRoutePoints removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                         [self performSelector:@selector(geolocateRoutePoint:)
                                    withObject:mutableArrayWithRoutePoints afterDelay:3.0];

                         if (error) {
                             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                             return;
                         }

                         if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
                         {
                             CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                             CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
                             c.addressLatitude =  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
                             c.addressLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];

                             // Saving the context here after getting geocode.
                             // Definitely not the best place to save the context. 
                             // I will move this later to another place
                             NSError *error = nil;
                             if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                                 NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
                             }
                         }
                     }];
    }
    else
    {
        [mutableArrayWithRoutePoints removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(geolocateRoutePoint:)
                   withObject:mutableArrayWithRoutePoints];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think what that doesn't take into account is the fact that with a very fast connection you could still easily end up with more than 50 geocodes per minute. Why not just use `NSTimer` to iterate through your address strings until there are none left?

Comment: The problem is not the very fast connection, but the imposed limit of 50 requests per minute when geocoding as I said before. I think the intention of Apple doing this is to prevent the abuse of doing a HUGE number of geocoding in a short time and overload the servers.