# Human readable location in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocation, clgeocoder

Since the 6.1 update I can only reverse the first 25% of all the photos containing CLLocation information.

After the first 25% I get for all the others: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)".

I am processing all the images so maybe I am calling the service too often too quickly? But not limitation on this regard is mentioned anywhere :S

Code

```
CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
if(location != nil){
    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        if(placemarks.count == 0){
            // this happens with more than 75% of the photos
            return;
        }
        // this only happens with the other 25%
    }];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619879/iphone-ios5-clgeocoder-how-to-geocode-a-large-200-set-of-addresses/10620181#10620181) which says that there's a limitation of 50 requests per unknown amount of time.